# Can't run my script

Tags: scripting

using Ubuntu 16. I have created this script and placed it in     `/root/s3backyupsync.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
################################################
# Simple script to synchronise data into S3 bucket(s)
# @Author: Per Lasse Baasch (https://skycube.net)
# @Version: 2016-01-27
#############################################
LOCALDIR='/mnt/backups'
S3BUCKET='s3://server-backups/'
MAILLOG=yes
MAILRECEIPIENT='youremail@gmail.com'
MAILSUBJECT='Daily S3 Cloud Backup Sync'
#############################################

### Remember start time
CURRENTDATETIME=$(date +%Y-%m-%-d-%H:%M:%S);

### Sync data
s3cmd sync --no-progress --recursive --skip-existing --no-check-md5  $LOCALDIR $S3BUCKET;

### Mailing
if [ "${MAILLOG}" = "yes" ]; then
        TMPFILE=/tmp/s3backupsynclog.txt;
        echo "STARTED: ${CURRENTDATETIME}" > $TMPFILE;
        echo "ENDED  : $(date +%Y-%m-%-d-%H:%M:%S)" >> $TMPFILE;
        echo '' >> $TMPFILE;
        s3cmd du -H $S3BUCKET >> $TMPFILE;
        echo '' >> $TMPFILE;
        mutt $MAILRECEIPIENT -s "${MAILSUBJECT}. - ${CURRENTDATETIME}" < $TMPFILE;
    rm $TMPFILE;
fi
```

When I try to run it either with sudo or root like `root/s3backyupsync.sh` I get command not found. Am I missing something?

Results of `ls -l /root/s3backyupsync.sh`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1013 Sep 15 15:05 /root/s3backyupsync.sh
```

Comment: Please show us the *exact* commands you tried to run and also tell us whether the script is executable (show us the output of `ls -l /root/s3backyupsync.sh`)

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1013 Sep 15 15:05 /root/s3backyupsync.sh

Comment: I tried writing just sudo /root/s3backyupsync.sh as a user and also as root /root/s3backyupsync.sh

Comment: Thanks but please add that to your question. Comments are easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. Make sure to also show us the exact commands as requested. What happens if you just run `sudo /root/s3backyupsync.sh`? What exact error message? Please [edit] your question and include all this.

Comment: should i change the first line: #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash  ? I have another script in root which works fine when calling it like that

Comment: Did you copy this file from a Windows machine?  Maybe you need to `dos2unix` it to convert it to Unix format.

Comment: no i created the file directly on the server using nano and pasted the contents from the web inside..

Comment: OK, just to rule some things out. Please *[edit]* your question and show us what happens (including the exact wording of the error) if you run `sudo sh /root/s3backyupsync.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `#!/bin/bash` first. Also try going into the directory and type `./s3backyupsync.sh`

Comment: No Problem , just saw you figured it out yourself :)

Comment: #!/bin/bash/ has no function. Its a comment...

Comment: It has a function !
It tells the shell what program to interpret the script with. 
#!/bin/bash — Execute the file using bash, the Bourne shell, or a compatible shell

Comment: You probably don't want the trailing `/` on your shebang

Comment: Sry you are right.Fixed it.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai are you sure? That makes absolutely no sense. There are no bashisms that I can see in your script, so `#!/bin/sh` is fine, and anyway, you'd have gotten a completely different error if that were the problem.